# Join 2 tables and use where in same query

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to join 2 tables (1.5KK and 500K records) but only on some records of the first table. I try this

```
SELECT Table1.col1 AS NCol1, Table1.col2 AS NCol2, Table2.col1 AS NCol3
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.col3 = Table2.col3
WHERE Table1.col1 = value
```

but SQLite get stuck. I use DB browser for SQLite and i cant get response.

Works greate if i do

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TEMP_JOIN AS
SELECT Table1.col1 AS NCol1, Table1.col2 AS NCol2, Table2.col1 AS NCol3
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.col3 = Table2.col3;

SELECT * FROM TEMP_JOIN WHERE NCol1 = value
```

I want to use the first code, what fix i need to do to make that work?

Comment: what do you mean gets stuck? that's really not that much data tbh

Comment: For best results you'd want indexes on Table2.col3 and Table1.col1 if you don't already. Wouldn't hurt to run a `PRAGMA optimize` after, too.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use `LEFT JOIN` or would an `INNER JOIN` suffice?  If so, that would certainly help performance.

Comment: @aws_apprentice The query did not finish, i wait for 1 hour and the DB Browser still calculate. English its not my native language so i supposed stuck is the word.

Comment: @Shawn Still doesn't work :(

Comment: @InfiniteHigh Yes, I need keep all records from Table1 where col1 = value, and Table2 have a part of record of Table1.

Comment: @VicenteMarambio if col3 in Table2 is not null, `INNER JOIN` would suffice

Comment: @InfiniteHigh How i can do that? i don't understand :(

Comment: @VicenteMarambio see this link for an explanation of SQL joins: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/ .  A `LEFT JOIN` is only appropriate in this instance if some data in Table2 can have a value of `null` for col3.  If the column can't be `null`, `INNER JOIN` will capture all of the correct rows. Simply replace your `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`.